# Cursor foreach on timed intervals

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor sever code needs to print out the the document from a collection once every n seconds, How do I get it to work? thx

```js
      myCol.find({abc: undefined}).forEach(
        function (doc) {
          setTimeout(function (doc) {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
          }, 1000)
        }
      )
```

2 problems: the doc is undefined and the timer is not activated, thus it just fires all at once.

Comment: "the doc is undefined" you need to solve this via the find method documentation or the forEach one. I have no idea about what the find or forEach do in the API terms. But about the timeout, here is the thing. Do you know how asynchronous events work in JS? They'll fire all it once, since they are added to a stack, all with approximately 1000 ms, and yes they fire one after one immediately, without waiting 1000ms after each other, because they wait 1000ms after you code finished execution. You need to set the timer function only for the first occurrence, and inside it set the subsequent timers

Comment: In regards to the timer problem solution, are you able to give an example in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need not an example but the essential understanding of the event model in JS. JS is a single threaded language, and when you add any assync function whether via `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `requestAnimationFrame` you add it to the stack. And the engine, if conditions are met, fires the functions one by one after the current thread was finished.

In you example this is what happening: in the forEach function you are adding the annon function, which is called for every element.

So the collection is being traversed **in the single thread**. In this thread the annon function is adding the timeout functions, but they are not called immediatelly. They are added to the stack. And functions from this stack are not called until the current thread (in this case your traversal through the collection) finished being executed.

After your current thread is finished, the JS engine takes functions from the stack and checks whether the conditions for the current functions are met (like 1000ms from the time it was added to the stack). Since for all your added timeout callbacks the condition was met (1000ms, if they passed for the first callback, then they surely passed for the subsequent ones). They are fired one by one, which looks to you as all at once.

The example would be:

```
var i = 0;
function traverseInLoop() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(myCol[i]));
  if (myCol(++i) {
    setTimeout(traverseInLoop, 1000)
  }
}
setTimeout(traverseInLoop, 1000);
```

Or something like that, you should get the idea, but if you don't, then tell me, I'll elaborate